# Chrome Extension Opens new tab, send message to new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an App page (extension_id://app.html)
I want to create a new tab:

```
let tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: candidate_url });
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab['id'], {"message": "sendMessage", "data": {}, "tabID": tab['id']});
```

however, when I send a message to this tab id it doesnt work.

here is the content.js script, but it doesn't alert or console log

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "sendMessage"){
            console.log("XX");
            alert("XX");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: when you create that new tab you can't send it a message at least not before it is ready to receive it.

Comment: @Robbi then do you suggest that I add a setTimeout or a "sleep" function before I send the message to the new tab?

Comment: no, in background script use a event handler like chrome.tabs.onUpdate and when the status will be "complete" then send your message.

Comment: ok, but then how do I listen for that event in my app page script?

Comment: @Robbi after adding the setTimeout for about 5 seconds it works perfectly. Thank you for the help ;)

Comment: it is not the right way. A page could take more the 10 seconds to be ready for receiving message. See docs for tabs events at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: @Robbi how can i send key press to a editablecontent div? I cannot use jquery trigger, it must be with vinilla js. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a setTimeout to call the send function works correctly, just have to have the page load and timer called perfectly, about 8 to 10 seconds is enough time for the page to load.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue but I went down the path as @Robbi would approach it above (without the timeout/sleep/delay hack ;) ):

```js
const tabLoadingTrap = { tabId: undefined, resolve: undefined };

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo) => {
  if (tabId === tabLoadingTrap.tabId && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    tabLoadingTrap.resolve();

    Object.assign(tabLoadingTrap, { tabId: undefined, resolve: undefined });
  }
});

(async () => {
  const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://example.com' });
  await waitForTabLoadingToComplete(tab.id);
  const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { greeting: 'hello' });
  console.log(response);
})();

function waitForTabLoadingToComplete(tabId) {
  tabLoadingTrap.tabId = tabId;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    tabLoadingTrap.resolve = resolve;
  });
}
```